# SFCC - How show products from Stored Basket?

Tags: javascript, commerce-cloud

I have the situation:
The Stored Basket (registered customer) is merging with the current Basket (anonymous customer), this is ok, but i need to highlight the products from Stored Basket to the customer knows which product is current and which product is from stored.

The problem is when i call the class :

```
var BasketMgr = require('dw/order/BasketMgr');
var currentBasket = BasketMgr.getCurrentOrNewBasket();
var storedBasket = BasketMgr.getStoredBasket();
```

I dont know how i can extract the products from the Stored after the merge.

Someone can give me a tip?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you need just take a collection with products from the basket.

```
var extractedProducts = [chosebBasket].getProductLineItems();
```